Sprites disappear when starting a game on a phone made with Unity
I have a web game. When I run it on unity, everything works well, when I run it on the platform from a computer, everything is fine too. BUT when I launch on the platform from my phone, pink squares appear instead of sprites. Moreover, they appear only instead of sprites taken from one sprite atlas
I absolutely do not understand how to fix this and what is the reason for it

sounds like the shader doesnt work on your phone

you are probably using some shaders that dont work on mobile. to check errors on phone and further examination please install and implement log viewer
this helps you see logs and errors on mobile.
